# Kann man den Artikel in „zum“ in diesem Satz weglassen?

Tags: grammar, difference, article, time

> Ich bleibe vom 21. September bis zum 24. Dezember in Hamburg.

Kann man den Artikel in diesem Satz weglassen?

> Ich bleibe vom 21. September bis zu 24. Dezember in Hamburg.

Wenn man den Artikel in diesem Zusammenhang auslässt, wird sich dadurch die Bedeutung des Satzes ändern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die Bedeutung ändert sich nicht, der Satz wird nur grammatikalisch falsch.

Answer (score 1):

Ich nehme an, mit *Artikel* ist die Zusammenziehung von *zu dem* zu *zum* gemeint. Mit *zu* ist der Satz zwar noch verständlich, klingt aber fremd. Wenn es kürzer sein soll, würde ich zu dieser Formulierung raten:

> Ich bleibe von 21. September bis 24. Dezember in Hamburg.

Die Datumsangaben sind immer noch im Dativ, d. h. aussprechen würde man "von einundzwanzigstem September".

Comment: _von_ statt _vom_ klingt für mich eindeutig falsch, bzw. sieht geschrieben aus wie ein Tippfehler. Hast Du einen Beleg dafür?

Comment: ".... von September bis Dezember" ginge, so aber meine ich nicht.Belege/Begründung aber Fehlanzeige.

Comment: Die vorgeschlagene Alternative klingt für mich etwas nicht-standard aber auf keinen Fall ganz falsch. Allerdings würde ich sie auf jeden Fall "von einundzwanzigsteR September bis vierundzwanzigsteR Dezember" aussprechen.

Comment: "Von September bis Dezember" geht, aber sowohl "von einundzwanzigsteM September bis vierundzwanzigsteM Dezember" als auch "von einundzwanzigsteR September bis vierundzwanzigsteR Dezember" klingt für mich als Muttersprachler einfach nur falsch.

Comment: "von" wird laut canoo mit Dativ benutzt, ist einfach eine Regel, wie guidot schon sagte: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Dativ.html
Der Dativ Singular von September ist "dem September". Das heißt also, "von dem September" oder kurz "vom September" sind richtig (auch wenn "von dem" unkonventionell klingt). Wenn man nur "von September" schreibt, unterschlägt man das "Dativ-M".
Für die Deklination von Zahlwörtern hab ich leider keine Regeln/Belege im Internet gefunden, vielleicht wird ja jemand anders noch fündig. (Obwohl man ja kasusunabhängig "21." schreibt.)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Ordnungszahlen) sagt: `Ordnungszahlen werden wie normale Adjektive dekliniert: „am ersten Mai, ein erster Anfang, die ersten Blüten“. `

Answer (score 1):

"Ich bleibe vom 21. September bis **zu** 24. Dezember in Hamburg."

Würde im Deutschen etwas merkwürdig klingen.

Das erste Satzbeispiel ist richtig.

Comment: Willkommen bei GermanSE! Könntest du hinzufügen, warum deiner Meinung nach deine Antwort etwas Neues beinhaltet?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34730)